# Java blocks my (signed .jar) applet due to security reasons. How do i fix this?

Tags: java, jar, applet, client, blocked

First i would like to say that the .jar does not contain any malicious software or code. It's not harmfull, everything is fine. I signed my .jar and I'm trying to load it into my website using this code:

```
<applet width="765" height="503" code="Loader.java" archive="HolyDivinity718V1.1.jar" name="Holy Divinity"></applet></p>
```

But when i run it i get this error:

```
Application Blocked. Click for details. Your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running.
```

The client is a webclient of a game that I'm running. What's the reason that it's getting blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [recently](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u51-relnotes-2085002.html) all self signed java applets are blocked. You can do one of the following things:

1. Buy and sign your applet with an official certificate
2. Decrease your security slider to medium
3. Use the [exception site list](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/upcoming_exception_site_list_in)
4. Sign your app with a self signed certificate and add your certificate to the java trust store